# SSH Key generation without pressing enter

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, ssh, automation

I am trying to write a Bash Script for generating ssh key. I am facing the issue of pressing enter while it ask for passfree .How will i make it work without pressing enter.

Follow below link it will ask for pressing enter.

[ssh installation normal process](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
   ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -P ""
```

That will not ask neither for destination file nor passphrase

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -m pem <<< y` is better；
[duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235179/how-to-execute-ssh-keygen-without-prompt)